# Does removing property from google search console remove the website from search results?

Tags: html, seo, google-search

I removed property (website) from google search console. The purpose was to remove the website from the search engine results. I did right or should I do different?

I had a website and decided to switch domain name. I decided to remove the old website (property) from google search console and start the indexing from scratch the website with the new domain name.

Now I`m still seeing the old website on search results. Does removing property from google search console work to remove the website from search results?   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, removing a website from Google search console doesn't remove it from search results.  Many sites don't use Google search console, yet Google indexes them.

Add the following meta tag to all pages:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

You can also use `robots.txt` with the following content to prevent Google from indexing your site:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

The former will prevent your site from showing in search results.  The latter will prevent Google from indexing your site, but it may still be show in search results if there are links to it.

See more here:

https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608